# is there a shortcut to open filter>contains box in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I use filters a lot.

Filter > contains option

But it is slow because everytime i need to do several clicks.

So, my question is, is there a shortcut to open filter, drop down, contains window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you start with filtered data already, you need to have the header cell selected.  From there: <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DOWN</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>.

If the filter is not already created then throw in a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> at at the start.

If you are not in the header row, some combination of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ARROW</kbd> keys can get you there.  Ideally you have a block of data and can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>UP</kbd> if you start in the correct column.